# Link disappears in only 1 section in Outlook '16

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, outlook, dynamic-content

I have an email that is populated via Dynamic Content and there's just one section of the email where the URL disappears only in Outlook 16.  If you "view source" the URL is there.  If you click "View Online" the URL is there.  The URL works just fine in other platforms.  The HTML code has not changed (except for the URL itself) and was working fine as of last week.

**Has anyone seen such a thing?  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot the issue?**

Screenshot is attached.

[image]

Comment: Any further context you can provide or code snippet would be appreciated It could be something along the lines of MSO conditional breaking the link, or if its triggering some sort of filter in Outlook that removes the link, etc.

Comment: @Gortonington - again you've made my day. YES, it's the MSO conditional content. I was able to get the link to work, but it's not redirecting.

The issue indeed was the MSO Conditional Content - it was not breaking the link, but the URL was missing altogether from the conditional code content.

partial code:
`<!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="%%=RedirectTo(@1a_button_URL)=%%" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#00AB99">
    <w:anchorlock/>`

Comment: For the buttons, you can also use this page as a reference: https://buttons.cm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Pulling in answer from comments for easy reference***

---

It could be something along the lines of MSO conditional breaking the link, or if its triggering some sort of filter in Outlook that removes the link, etc.

---

it's the MSO conditional content. I was able to get the link to work. The issue indeed was the MSO Conditional Content - it was not breaking the link, but the URL was missing altogether from the conditional code content. partial code: `<!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="%%=RedirectTo(@1a_button_URL)=%%" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#00AB99"> <w:anchorlock/>`

[image: Button Works Now]

Comment: I actually was able to get tracking to work, the issue was how I coded it, so the MSO link IS being tracked, in case you want to update the answer (which I will then "check off"!)

Comment: Are you positive on that? I just verified in my own account that the MSO conditional button I created, almost exactly mimicing your code, did not get wrapped for SFMC tracking, but instead displayed the raw link. (e.g. http://www.google.com)

Comment: Yes - and I have a screenshot, but I don't know how to post the image or code in the comments section.

Comment: If you could edit either your question or my answer to include your final code, that would be awesome.  I will remove the link tracking part from my answer now. I am very interested to see this!